# Ubuntu command line move mouse cursor? for hiding cursor

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, gnome

In a HTML kiosk app, my mouse cursor just stuck at middle of the screen, which I don't really wanna show it.

I also know that you can change mouse cursor image to fake it disappearance. But I will give some inconvenience when you actually wanna have it back...

Any simple command line can move the mouse cursor? e.g. to the bottom right corner of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can auto-hide the mouse cursor with **[`Unclutter`](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/07/07/auto-hide-your-mouse-pointer-when-idle-with-unclutter/)**

http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/07/07/auto-hide-your-mouse-pointer-when-idle-with-unclutter/

> #### Auto-Hide Your Mouse Pointer with Unclutter
>
> The purpose of Unclutter is very simply.  From the man page:
>
> > > unclutter removes the cursor image from the screen so that it does not obstruct the area you are looking at after it has not moved for a given time.
>
> Not anything too complicated about that.  Now lets get it installed!  Installation can be done by issuing the following command or clicking the link.
>
> > > ```
> > > sudo aptitude install unclutter
> > > ```

[...]

> > > ```
> > > unclutter -display :0.0 -idle 5
> > > ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html) to do that [and more](http://xmodulo.com/simulate-key-press-mouse-movement-linux.html)

```
xdotool mousemove 0 0
```